# Error in rle(toplevel) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type

Tags: r, shiny, publishing

I am trying to publish an app in `shiny` and when I click `publish` I receive the following error:

```
Error in rle(toplevel) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type.
```

It appears the returned value of `eventReactive` is not what was hoped for ([sic] nor correct), but I don't know how to proceed with the problem. My code is below and I appreciate your help.

```
# Load the ggplot2 package which provides
# the 'mpg' dataset.
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)

function(input, output) {
    auto_parts <- read_excel("./Auto-parts-bien2.xlsx", col_types = c("text", "text", "text",  "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric",  "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))

    re <- eventReactive(input$update,{
        data <- data.frame(auto_parts)
        data <- data[(data$Market.Value..EUR. >= input$marketcap[[1]])&(data$Market.Value..EUR. <= input$marketcap[[2]]),]
        data <- data[(data$Price.to.Earnings >= input$per[[1]])&(data$Price.to.Earnings <= input$per[[2]]),]
        data <- data[(data$Price.to.Book >= input$pb[[1]])&(data$Price.to.Book <= input$pb[[2]]),]
        data <- data[(data$Price.Index.48.m >= input$growth[[1]])&(data$Price.Index.48.m <= input$growth[[2]]),]
        data <- data[(data$ROIC.5.yr.avg >= input$roic[[1]])&(data$ROIC.5.yr.avg <= input$roic[[2]]),]
        if(input$ebitda == "Positive"){
            data <- data[data$X5yr.Growth.EBITDA >= 0,]
        }else {
            data <- data[data$X5yr.Growth.EBITDA <= 0,]
        }
        if(input$country != "All"){
            data <- data[data$Country == input$country,]
        }
        drop <- c("Piotroski.F.Score","Price.Index.12.m","Price.Index.48.m","X5yr.Growth.EBITDA"
                  ,"ROIC.5.yr.avg","Price.to.Sales","Fcf.Yield.5.yr.avg")
        data_2 <- data[!(names(data) %in% drop)]
        as.matrix.data.frame(data_2)
    })
    # Filter data based on selections
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
         re()
    }))

}
```

Comment: En la linea function(input, output), has llamado su funcion algo, en la forma, `mi_funcion <- function(input,output) {` ?

Comment: After 5 days getting crazy with this. I've solved the issue. It was not related with the code, the path where the app was, had strange characters. Hope it helps for all of you

Comment: write your solution as an answer, wait a little while, then accept your own answer. That completes the process here.

Answer (score 3):

After 5 days getting crazy with this. I've solved the issue. It was not related with the code, the path where the app was, had strange characters. Hope it helps for all of you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The problem was on the path of my files, I had a folder with this character: á

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, however my filepath did not have any special characters.

Instead I've used `rsconnect::deployApp()` in the console, which does work for me. Even after deployment the publish button still throws an error. Bit puzzled.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31302692)